# jQuery prepend() stringifies argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, prepend

I have the following code:

```
sections=$("section");
for(let i=0; i<sections.length; i++){
    let sectionTempCode=("<button id='").concat(i.toString()).concat("'>Toggle section view</button>");
    console.log(sectionTempCode)
    sections[i].prepend(sectionTempCode)
}
```

The intention is to add button tags to the HTML and display a button in the beginning of each . Instead, what I get is the code for the tag inside double quotes, which results in the code itself being displayed in my page:

```
"<button id='0'>Toggle section view</button>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` and the Elements generator `$(HTMLTag, {...properties})`

```js
$("section").each((i, el) => {

  $("<button>", {
    prependTo: el,
    id: i+1,
    type: "button",
    text: "Toggle section view",
    click() {
      console.log(this.id);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```